# unintended undies in the logo

Tags: discussion

I can only apologise for this, but I thought it fair to warn that I mostly see a circle wearing a pair of tightie whities / y fronts (and surely I'm not the only one?):

[image: undies logo]

This came up today due to a discussion about a similar logo... https://blog.rjmetrics.com/2013/10/09/our-logo-looks-like-underpants-a-case-study-in-internationalization/

Comment: So, you're saying the logo is totally pants

Comment: Thank you. Until now I always loved this nice minimalistic artificial horizon...

Comment: Once seen, can't unsee?

Comment: Try as I might, I can't see it. The lines are totally the wrong shape for Y-fronts. (And yes, I'm wearing them *right now*.)